# Replacement of Matlab's fntlr function in Python

Tags: python, matlab

Hii I am trying to convert the MATLAB code to python but I am stuck over a function of MATLAB i.e fntlr
and I am not understanding what to use instead of this function.

Comment: what libraries are you using?

Comment: @nadapez Curve fitting toolbox of matlab is used but what to use for python in not understanding